# SourceTreeでブックマークした(Local)リポジトリのパスを変更したい

Tags: sourcetree

SourceTree 2.6.6 Windows版を利用しています。OSはWindows 10です。

RemoteではなくLocalでブックマークしてあるgitリポジトリのファイルパスを変更したいです。

ファイルサーバーのホスト名が変わったので、設定ファイル等で複数のブックマーク先をまとめて変更することができると良いのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。

現状、GUI上で作り直す方法しか分かっていません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

冷静に調べてみると、[情報](https://ja.confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/edit-sourcetree-configurations-without-opening-the-application-windows-785323524.html)がありました。

```
C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml
```

bookmarks.xml内のパスを置換することで対処できました。